# SQL query error when exporting using bcp

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv, bcp

I have following query and exported the results into `csv` file using **bcp**:

```
select c.customer_no,
       c.cust_name,
       (select a.address 
        from   tblAddress a 
        where  a.pkey = b.delivery_address_pkey
       ) delivery_address,
       c.phone,
       (select a.address 
        from   tblAddress a 
        where  a.pkey = b.shipping_address_pkey
       ) Shipping_address
from address a 
  inner join delshipinfo b on a.pkey = b.delivery_address_pkey 
                          and a.pkey = b.shipping_address_pkey
  inner join customerinfo c on c.pkey = b.cust_pkey
```

My deliver address value is like `(blk 17B) First cross street`.

After exporting using **bcp** when I open the file `(blk 17B)` is placed in Address cell, `First cross street` placed in next cell. The data `(blk 17B) First cross street` should be coming in single cell under address.

How do I quote this to make the address field come into single cell. Double quotes dont work also. Please advise.

Comment: could you provide sample data and how it comes out wrong ? and how it should come out right ?

Comment: Hi GuidoG, My filed address value is like '(blk 17B) First cross street'. after exporting using bcp when i open the file (blk 17B) is placed in Address cell, First cross street placed in next cell. The data (blk 17B) First cross street should be coming in single cell under address

Comment: You should edit your question and put this info in there so people dont have to dig through comments to find it. That way you will get more answers

Comment: Give as much details as you can

Comment: can you share a code which runs this query?